# jmeter agents running specific tests

Tags: jmeter, using, agents

I want to run a Jmeter test using multiple agents but I don't want each agent to run the same test.

How can I assign specific tests (thread groups) to a specific agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually all JMeter remote slaves execute the same test plan so all the slaves should be doing the same stuff.

However you can change this behaviour by a trick with the help of the [IF Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function like:

```
"${__machineIP()}" == "your_remote_slave_IP_address"
```

Demo:

[image: Machine IP + If Controller]

As you can see, "Sampler 2" it **not** executed as IP address of the machine doesn't match the one, specified in the IF Controller